Modeling longitudinal data when the amount of time between points is different per individual
I am working with a repeated measures clinical dataset that includes a baseline assessment and a post-discharge assessment (so only a pre- and post- measure). Every participant in the dataset has the same number of points. However, the distance between points is different for each participant. One participant might've been discharged in one year, another in several. I want to model the effect of condition and time on my intervention outcomes. I want to account for the effect of distance between time points in my analysis, more interested on the end of seeing if it has an effect rather than controlling for it/removing variance attributed to time between points. However, I am not sure of the best way to go about this. Would it be possible to run a repeated measures ANCOVA with time between points as a covariate? What about a multilevel model with time between points as a covariate? Would one approach be better in this case than the other? Or is there another analysis that I am totally missing?
Would also appreciate any citations that might explain the issue in a bit more detail. Thank you for any feedback!

Don't do repeated measures ancova (ever?). You can do this as a multilevel model.
You might also consider having some sort of survival model in there too - can you predict why a person was discharged sooner? The book 'Applied longitudinal data analysis' by Singer and Willett is my favorite for this sort of thing (and the UCLA website has (or used to have) examples from the book in many different software packages.
